# Array mongoose express

Tags: nodejs, mongodb

El problema es el seguiente

quisiera saber la manera de poder guardar un array de datos en el model no lo tengo muy claro

mi model es asi

```
    let Schema = mongoose.Schema;
let Response = new Schema({
    say: {
        String
    },
    digit: {
        type: Number
    }
});
let Gather = new Schema({
    user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Usuario'
    },
    title: {
        type: String
    },
    gathers: [Response]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Gather', Gather);
```

pero como hago para guardar varios elementos los datos recuperados por el request hay que hacer por ejemplo insertar primeiro los datos title y eso despues hacer un loop y actualizar?

Comment: Una pregunta ¿Porqué defines 2 esquemas en el mismo módulo? Exactamente ¿qué deseas lograr?

Comment: lo que quiero lograr es donde los guathers ai tenga multiplos arrays

Comment: por ejemplo ghaters = [

Answer (score 3):

Por lo que puedo entender de tu pregunta, deseas saber cómo crear tu esquema, de tal manera que el modelo acepte un `Array` al que le agregarás diferentes elementos al momento de su uso.

En primer lugar, debes separar esos esquemas. Una buena práctica es poner un modelo por archivo. Así las cosas fluyen adecuadamente y te apegas a la filosofía Unix: "Una sola cosa, bien hecha".

**PROBLEMA**

Me voy a enfocar en tu duda específica. ¿Cómo guardar un array en un modelo?

**SOLUCIÓN**

La solución está en la forma en la que vas a construir el esquema. Como es de esperar, a cada atributo del esquema le estas pasando un tipo. Tal vez no recuerdas que `Array` también es un tipo permitido en un esquema de Mongoose. Puedes ver más información en [Schema Types](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html).

Entonces, lo que debes hacer es crear tu esquema de una forma parecida a la siguiente (supongamos que pones esto en un archivo llamado `gather.model.js`):

```
//Usando ES6 import:
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

// Puedes usar 'const', el esquema no va a variar
const GatherSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Usuario'
    },
    title: {
        type: String
    },
    gathers: {
        // aqui indicas que el tipo de dato es Array
        type: Array,
        // aqui lo inicializas por defecto como un array vacío
        default: []
    }
});

// ahora declaras el modelo y lo exportas
export default mongoose.model('Gather', GatherSchema);
```

En caso que no uses `ES6 import`, entonces este sería el código para `ES5 require`:

```
//Usando ES5
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const GatherSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Usuario'
    },
    title: {
        type: String
    },
    gathers: {
        // aqui indicas que el tipo de dato es Array
        type: Array,
        // aqui lo inicializas por defecto como un array vacío
        default: []
    }
});

// ahora declaras el modelo y lo exportas
module.exports = mongoose.model('Gather', GatherSchema);
```

Ahora ya puedes usar tu modelo, como no sé exactamente lo que deseas hacer con el modelo, no puedo darte un ejemplo de caso de uso.

Espero que esta sea la respuesta que buscas.

Comment: Hola @Maurico excelente respuesta, yo andaba buscando un ejemplo y justo di con tu respuesta. Crees que sería mucho pedir que nos expliques ¿cómo se realizaría un post a la colección, ¿como añadiría elementos al array? ¿O es un que es un post normal? Porfavor, es que ando buscando un ejemplo porque quiero guardar una lista de string en un array en donde la colección sea algo como: id: "xx", descripción: 0 : ['Algo'] 1: ["Más Algo"]

Comment: @Izlia, la pregunta es específica para un problema particular. Te invito a realizar tu propia pregunta, o en su defecto puedes buscarme en el [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol) del sitio. Si no estoy al momento, puedes hacerme mención y seguro te responderé. Saludos